# Accordion nested in Tab not appearing

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion

I'm attempting to place a jQuery accordion within a jQuery tab pane, and think there may be a conflict with the code I am using for the tabs as it is not appearing when inserted. The accordion works fine when in its own page. The script that appears in the page head is:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="v3flashslideshow/slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToByScroll(id){
                 $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
        }
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
```

The script at the end of the page is:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".tabs:first").tabs(".css-panes:first > div", { history: true });
});
$(function() {
$("#accordion").tabs(
"#accordion div.pane",
{tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null}
```

);
    });

```
</script>
</body>
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong? I'm a total newbie to jQuery, and just can't figure out where it is going wrong. The HTML all appears to be correct and can be [viewed here](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expedition_leader.html).

Any help with this appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using jQuery UI and jQuery tools together? jQuery UI can do tabs and accordions and I know from personal experience that they work together. Also, remove the awful MM_ code which I assume was inserted automatically by dreamweaver ;)

Comment: I know they can work together as well, otherwise I wouldn't be posting here. I've removed the  UI tool link, but that has made no difference. As I said, I'm a newbie. And as for the MM_code, it is neccesary for my JumpMenu functionality.

Comment: Can you post the HTML mark-up the tabs and accordion are built from? Seriously, any code automatically added by dreamweaver pretty much sucks. You don't need to use eval (which is evil!) just to create a simple select box navigation widget. Even that though is a pretty dated technique - a select element is *not* a semantic accessible navigation device

Comment: The HTML is pretty lengthy and is probably best viewed via the test page [here](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expedition_leader.html). I originally coded up the tab and accordion elements separately based on jquerytools, and now am having trouble combining them onto the same page. They are fine on separate pages. I think the problem is with the jQuery code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hmm. Can't see anything obviously wrong. I note that the jQuery tools example page for tabs and accordions specifically *doesn't* show a demo that shows an accordion inside a tab, although it does show multiple tabs and multiple accordions...maybe it just isn't possible. Or is a bug. jQuery UI - the *official* UI library for jQuery can handle accordions within tabs...